# How to echo a variable from the function

Tags: php

How to echo a variable from the function? This is an example code.

```
function test() {
  $foo = 'foo';   //the variable
}

test();   //executing the function

echo $foo;   // no results in printing it out
```

Comment: Are you just trying to print the variable?  Why not print it inside the function?  Are you trying to return it?  Or are you just trying to print it AFTER returning?

Comment: you cannot print a variable which isn't declared before the function.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The immediate answer to your question would be to import `$foo` into the function's scope:

```
function test() {

  global $foo;
  $foo = 'foo';   //the variable
}
```

More on variable scope in PHP [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

this is, however, bad practice in most cases. You will usually want to *return* the desired value from the function, and assign it to `$foo` when calling the function.

```
   function test()
    { 
      return "foo"; 
     }

   $foo = test();

   echo $foo;  // outputs "foo"
```

Answer (score 3):

The variable life scope is just inside the function. You need to declare it global to be able to access it outside the function.

You can do:

```
function test() {
  $foo = 'foo';   //the variable
  echo $foo;
}

test();   //executing the function
```

Or declare it global as suggested. To do it so, have a look at the manual here:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Answer (score 2):

```
function test() {
  return 'foo';   //the variable
}

$foo = test();   //executing the function

echo $foo;
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `$foo` variable is not visible outside of the function, because it exists only in the function's scope. You can do what you want several ways:

Echo from a function itself:

```
function test() {
    $foo = 'foo';
    echo $foo;
}
```

Echo a return result:

```
function test() {
    $foo = 'foo';   //the variable
    return $foo;
}

echo test();   //executing the function
```

Make the variable global

```
$foo = '';

function test() {
    Global $foo;
    $foo = 'foo';   //the variable
}

test();   //executing the function

echo $foo;
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would do.

```
function test(&$foo)
{
    $foo = 'bar';
}

test($foobar);

echo $foobar;
```

Using the ampersand within the function parameters section tells the function to "globalization" the input variables so any changes to that variable will directly change the one outside the function scope!

Comment: As long as $foobar is defined before calling test() for readability... despite the fact that PHP will create $foobar on the fly

Comment: $foobar should be created by PHP Outside its scope! without the user application creating it, so my example should work fine by creating $foobar within the outer scope! - http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php